# Python setup.py: import packages from subdirectories not specifying top level directory

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py, distutils

I am trying to write setup.py such that I will be able to import submodules from package_3 directly, without specifying top level (`from package_3 import submodule_1`), not as `from package_3.package_3 import submodule_1`, simultaneously being able to import any submodules from package_2 and package_1 as `from package_1 import submodule_1` and `from package_2 import submodule_1`

Directory tree:

```
├── package_3
│   └── package_3
│       └── __init__.py
│       └── submodule_1
|       |   └── __init__.py
|       └── submodule_2
|           └── __init__.py
├── package_2
│   └── __init__.py
|   └── submodule_1
|   |   └── __init__.py
|   └── submodule_2
|       └── __init__.py
├── package_1
│   └── __init__.py
|   └── submodule_1
|   |   └── __init__.py
|   └── submodule_2
|       └── __init__.py
├── setup.py
```

Could you tell me please if it is possible to achieve this using some specific configuration of setup.py without changes in directory tree (the only thing I can change is add or remove **init.py**)?

What I tried:

```
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(
  packages=setuptools.find_packages(
    include=["package_1", "package_2"]
  ) + setuptools.find_packages(include=['package_3'], where='./package_3')
 )
```

and then `pip install -e .`

Another configuration I tried:

```
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(
  packages=["package_1", "package_2", "package_3"],
  package_dir={
   'package_1': '.',
   'package_2': '.',
   'package_3': './package_3/package_3'
  } 
)
```

and then `pip install -e .`

Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an `__init__.py` of your "root-level" package_3 module to make it transparent, you could do something like :

```py
from .package_3 import submodule_1
```

The requested `from package_3 import submodule_1` should then work as requested.

Comment: This is not only "you could" but actually the only correct/the only pythonic answer to the question. That's kinda main purpose of (non-empty) init files - there's even a simple example in the docs https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules | And an example of a big lib using it: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/master/fastapi/__init__.py